# What are the names of these Boolean Algebraic Laws?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need to simplify a Boolean algebraic equation and name the laws I use at each step, here is where I am at

AB + AC + B

I got the answer online but couldn't identity the law

```
AB + AC + B
(AB + B) + AC (Is this the commutative law?)
B + AC   (Name of this law?)
```

Comment: In the first case, you have made use of the commutative law for $+$, (AC +B = B+AC), and also, in a sense you use the associative law as well:  $AB+B +AC = (AB+ B) + C = AB +(B+C)$

Comment: $AB+ B = B$ is the [absorption law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_law), which holds in all lattices.

Comment: Yes @Fabio, I the use of the  "absorption law" in "part II" of my answer below.  Never hurts, though, to know why the absorption law works, and the laws/properties, identities on which it depends. I've always found a firm knowledge base and understanding some basic laws and properties, and then using them as building blocks, to reach the laws that depend on them to be empowering.

Comment: @amWhy I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, (second line following the proposition), you have made use of the commutative law for $+$, $$(AC + B = B +AC)\tag{associativity}$$ and also, the associative law for $+$ is being used:  $$\color{blue}{(AB+B +AC)= ((AB+ B) + AC)} = (AB +(B+AC))\tag{commutativity}$$

$$ $$

To get to the second line $\large ^\left(\color{red}\dagger\right)$, we note that $B = 1\cdot B$, by the identity for "and".  Then we can use the distributive property of "and" over "or" to get $$(AB+B) = AB+ 1\cdot B = (A+1)B\tag{distributivity}$$

Now, $$A+1 = 1\tag{annihilator axiom for +}$$  so we can reduce $$(A+1)B = 1\cdot B = B\tag{identity: $1\cdot B = B$}$$

In the end, we have $$AB + B + AC = B+AC$$

$$ $$
$(\color{red} \dagger)$  By invoking the **axiom of absorption for "or"** we can immediately conclude: $$AB+B = B$$ giving us $$((AB+B)+AC) = B+AC$$

You might want to bookmark the following link: [Justifications(laws) of Boolean Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws). There  you'll find references to each reason listed above.

Comment: That works nicely, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, Ninja2k!

Answer (score 1):

Let's go step by step: your three term addition is actually $(AB+AC)+B$, so
\begin{align}
(AB+AC)+B
&=AB+(AC+B) && \text{associativity} \\
&=AB+(B+AC) && \text{commutativity} \\
&=(AB+B)+AC && \text{associativity} \\
&=(AB+1B)+AC && \text{by $B=1B$} \\
&=\bigl((A+1)B\bigr)+AC && \text{distributivity} \\
&=1B+AC && \text{by $A+1=1$} \\
&=B+AC && \text{by $B=1B$}
\end{align}
The steps marked “associativity” are usually not mentioned. Also
$$
AB+B=B
$$
follows from $AB\le B$, so a quicker derivation is
$$
AB+AC+B=AB+B+AC=B+AC
$$
where for the first equality we apply the commutative law.